Why does "assign a = a/2" (inside a task) only cause a single value change?
Today I encountered a very peculiar piece of test code, and everyone is stumped at why it operates the way it does. The simplified version of it would look something like this (please pay attention to the fact that the test is written inside a task):
task TEST();
    logic [9:0] a;

    assign a = 10'd512;
    #10ns;
    assign a = a/2;
    #100ns;

endtask


My questions are:

The expectation was that a would continue to be divided by 2 every unit of delta time, until its value reaches 0. But instead, in simulation (using Xcelium), it is only divided once, and the end result is a = 256. Why is that? A colleague confirmed with a small test that assign functions as normal in a task if the RHS does not contain the LHS variable. So I am guessing it has something to do with it essentially being an always@(...) block where the only variable in the sensitivity list is also the LHS variable, but I cannot find a description for what happens in that specific case anywhere.

I was confused why the code compiles successfully and even without any warnings while having 2 assign statements for the same variable. While searching for an answer, I found Section 10.6.1 of LRM version 1800-2017 says:



If the keyword assign is applied to a variable for which there is already a procedural continuous
assignment, then this new procedural continuous assignment shall deassign the variable before making the new procedural continuous assignment.

And now I am even more confused, why does the LRM say this, if having two assign statements for the same variable would generally cause compilation (multiple driver) errors in a module, instead of keeping the last assign statement and disregarding the others?


The scheduling semantics of continuous assignments are not clearly defined in the LRM. There is no delta time between the evaluation of the RHS and the update of the LHS--they both happen in the same active region. Note that the update may happen immediately, or placed in a queue. The LRM does not define an ordering between events within a region even though the term "queue" is used. That gives tools freedom to do the update before scheduling the sensitivity of the RHS.

You are confusing, structural continuous assignments with procedural continuous assignments. This is common since both constructs use the same assign keyword.


You can have multiple continuous assignments (drivers) on a net, but only one continuous assignment to a variable.
A procedural continuous assignment overrides all procedural assignments to a variable, and replaces any previous procedural continuous assignment to that variable.
Procedural continuous assignments were originally intended to model asynchronous behavior in a separate process from the synchronous behavior of a flip-flop. However, most synthesis tools have chosen to restrict the modeling of a flip-flop to a single (always) process. This construct is rarely used now.

Procedural assign statements and deassign statements are being considered for deprecation, IEEE1800-2023 C.4.2. But it been considered for deprecation since IEEE1800-2005 25.4 so who knows how long it will be until it is actually deprecated

Thank you Dave. I feel like this answers my second question, but I'm not sure about the first one. A procedural continuous statement is still "continuous", so why does assign a = a/2 not cause an infinite loop of the value getting updated? I assume this sort of code is bad practice, and am surprised it does not cause an error/warning (is there something specifically banning such code?). Should the outcome I described in my question be written down to being a tool-specific reaction to a bad coding practice, or is there some SV-related explanation for the value updating only once?
